# Code to implement personal voicemail in Skype

Tags: skype, skype4com, skype4java

I have a project where I will be receiving Skype calls from certain set of Skype users.
The user needs to be responded by a pre-defined message and then based on response will be directed to next stop (agent or call or another pre-recorded message).

I did found lot of DTMF and IVR implementation of Skype and tried implementing them, Everything works but the problem comes in playing the recorded message as Skype call response.
 Can somebody please help me how to write a C# code to change the audio source of skype to play a wav or mp3 file?

I have checked:

http://devforum.skype.com/t5/Desktop-API/Event-for-incoming-call/td-p/9174

http://community.skype.com/t5/Desktop-API-former-Public-API/Sending-Audio-in-Skype/td-p/422

[Send audio over skype call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8244530/send-audio-over-skype-call?rq=1)

to name some.
Can implement everything except playing the audio as skype response.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this thing using C#. if your call varrialbe is `CurrentCall`:

```
TCallIoDeviceType DeviceType = TCallIoDeviceType.callIoDeviceTypeFile;
CurrentCall.set_InputDevice(DeviceType, audio_file_directory);
```

Audio files must be mono WAV-s files.